# HTML Text Link just for onclick event, not for (re-)loading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a button, text link or whatever works in my text which triggers the `show` jQuery function. This function sets two divs to `display:block`. You can try the `show more` button below. With this one it is working.

At the moment I am facing the problem that if someone clicks on the link, the page slides up.  I just want to get triggered the jQuery function. How can I do this?

I am talking about the `Click here` link on [this webpage](https://www.countrycorn.com.au/charity-and-donations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_self" onclick="showImageAndFirstText()">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: anyway nice website !